# retreive google user info from tokenId

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

In my app, I have the google token Id as an input in String format. My question, is it possible to retreive with java google APIs the user info like (user name, mail ....).

I tried this example

```
Credential credential = GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(tokenId);
Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
Userinfoplus userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
return userinfo.getEmail();
```

I get the following error:

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting an ID token, this is probably what you need:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo